# How to pass a class (not an object) as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, arguments

**Introdutory note:** I started studying C++ in college about a month ago. This is for an assignment. We are staring out now and do not grasp many advanced concepts.

**tl;dr:** let's imagine you have a `Book`. The `Book` is a dynamic array of `Pages*`. Each `Page` can be a `WrittenPage` or a `DrawnPage`. If you want to print all the `Pages` you use a `virtual method`. If you just want to print the `DrawnPages` or `WrittenPages` you'll have to do some sort of filtering inside the `Book`. How to do that? For now I discovered you'll need `typeid` or some sort of other mean to compare the `subtype` of each `Page`. If you're in a hurry for something quick and simple take a look at the accepted answer, by @CantChooseUsernames. It's working well for my problem. If you have some more expertise I'd like to hear what you think about the new answer by @n.m. . Don't let the currently accepted answer discourage you from commenting or posting your own if you think it brings something new and meaningful to the discussion.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a class MyObj that's a superclass of TheseObj and ThoseObj.

```
Class TheseObj : public MyObj {
}

Class ThoseObj : public MyObj {
}
```

I have another class that contains an std::vector with pointers to MyObj instances and a non-static method in which I want to list only TheseObj:

```
Class MyClass {
    private:
    vector<MyObj*> vec;

    public:
    void listTheseObj() {
        for each (myObj* obj in vec) {
            if(typeid(*obj) == typeid(theseObj)) {
                cout << *obj << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All operators are already correctly overloaded.

This works great. Now the problem is that I have a lot more places where I need to do the same, so I'm in need of a template method that could receive a GENERIC vector and a class TYPE, in order for me to do something like:

```
listObjects(class_name_here, vec);
```

I managed to create:

```
template <class T>
void listObjectsOfOneType(const type_info& class_name_here, const vector<T*>& vec) {
    for each (T* obj in vec) {
        if(typeid(*obj) == typeid(class_name_here)) {
            cout << *obj << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure:

1. If the template method is right
2. How can I call it

Hope I've made myself clear, thank you very much in advance for your time.

Comment: "This works great" ― perhaps for very small values of great. You should be using virtual functions to run subtype-specific code. `typeid` is basically never the right thing to use.

Comment: How about posting something a bit more elaborate? If you could do some examples that'd be great.

Comment: I don't know what your real problem is. Is it really listing objects of some specific type, or something else?

Comment: It's exactly what I mentioned in my post. If you didn't read it of course it's hard to help.

Comment: In your question I can see a simplified example, unfit for production. I have no idea how well it represents your real code. I also don't know what is the intended audience of this functionality. If you want to print out a list of objects for debugging purposes, then as Daniel T. mentions in his answer, `typeid` is acceptable. If it's a part of your business logic, then it's better to avoid such usage of `typeid`. It violates Liskov Substitution Principle and is therefore prone to breakage when your class hierarchy is modified.

Comment: You could have said that in the first place. I started studying C++ in college about a month ago. This is for an assignment. We are staring out now and do not grasp many advanced concepts. I do see what you mean and it makes perfect sense. Still, is there any way of doing this that won't violate the substitution principle? Thanks for your input.

Comment: I will prepare an answer shortly, although you have already accepted one, because comments are inconvenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably avoid using TypeID.. Though, I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve but this is what I believe you are asking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T, class U>
void ListObjects(std::vector<U*> &vec)
{
    for (U* obj : vec)
    {
        if (typeid(*obj) == typeid(T))
        {
            obj->Print();
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
}

class Parent
{
    public:
        Parent() {std::cout<<"Parent Constructed\n";}
        virtual ~Parent() {std::cout<<"Parent Destructed\n";}

        virtual void Print(){std::cout<<"Parent\n";}
};

class Brother : public Parent
{
    public:
        Brother(){std::cout<<"Brother Constructed\n";}
        virtual ~Brother(){std::cout<<"Brother Destructed\n";}
        void Print() override {std::cout<<"Brother\n";}
};

class Sister : public Parent
{
    public:
        Sister(){std::cout<<"Sister Constructed\n";}
        virtual ~Sister(){std::cout<<"Sister Destructed\n";}
        void Print() override {std::cout<<"Sister\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Parent*> Objects;
    Objects.push_back(new Parent());
    Objects.push_back(new Brother());
    Objects.push_back(new Sister());
    std::cout<<"\n";

    ListObjects<Parent>(Objects);
    ListObjects<Brother>(Objects);
    ListObjects<Sister>(Objects);

    for (Parent* c : Objects)
    {
        delete c;
    }
}
```

Which prints:

- Parent Constructed
- Parent Constructed
- Brother Constructed
- Parent Constructed
- Sister Constructed
- Parent
- Brother
- Sister
- Parent Destructed
- Brother Destructed
- Parent Destructed
- Sister Destructed
- Parent Destructed
- Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.066 s
- Press any key to continue.

---

A lot of comments are telling you to use not use TypeID because we are NOT sure what you want.. However, what we mean by "there is no need for typeid" assuming that we know what you want, then the following would be valid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
void ListObjects(std::vector<T*> &vec)
{
    for (T* obj : vec)
    {
        //TypeID isn't needed here because the virtual call will figure out which class's << operator to call.

        //If each class has a print function, it can also figure out which class's print function to call..
        //obj->Print(); //works too because each class has a print func.
        std::cout<<*obj<<"\n"; //Works because each class has an overloaded << operator.
    }
}

class Parent
{
    protected:
        virtual void Print(std::ostream& os) const {os<<"Parent\n";}

    public:
        Parent() {std::cout<<"Parent Constructed\n";}
        virtual ~Parent() {std::cout<<"Parent Destructed\n";}

        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Parent &p);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Parent &p)
{
    p.Print(os);
    return os;
}

class Brother : public Parent
{
    protected:
        void Print(std::ostream& os) const override {os<<"Brother\n";}

    public:
        Brother(){std::cout<<"Brother Constructed\n";}

        virtual ~Brother() {std::cout<<"Brother Destructed\n";}
};

class Sister : public Parent
{
    protected:
        void Print(std::ostream& os) const override {os<<"Sister\n";}

    public:
        Sister(){std::cout<<"Sister Constructed\n";}
        virtual ~Sister(){std::cout<<"Sister Destructed\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Parent*> Objects;
    Objects.push_back(new Parent());
    Objects.push_back(new Brother());
    Objects.push_back(new Sister());
    std::cout<<"\n";

    ListObjects(Objects); //NOTICE we all template types are now inferred.

    for (Parent* c : Objects)
    {
        delete c;
    }
}
```

Notice in the above that since the call is virtual, the code prints the same as the code that uses TypeID and the code no longer needs you to type anything in the template's braces. It is inferred because we no longer need to compare using typeid.

---

Now since you requested the previous code with the template being a parameter instead, then:

```
template <class T, class U>
void ListObjects(std::vector<U*> &vec)
{
    for (U* obj : vec)
    {
        if (typeid(*obj) == typeid(T))
        {
            obj->Print();
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

would become:

```
template<typename T>
void ListObjects(std::vector<T*> &vec, const std::type_info &type)
{
    for (T* obj : vec)
    {
        if (typeid(*obj) == type)
        {
            std::cout<<*obj<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and you'd use it like: `ListObjects(Objects, typeid(Child));`

Again, all of these give you the exact same result. It all depends on your needs/use-case. We don't exactly know "what" you want to achieve. These should help you out though.

Comment: Thanks! That's almost what I'm looking for. The problem is that you need to do something like [ ListObjects<Parent, Brother>(Objects); ]. This way I'm forced to type in the superclass_name inside the diammond inference which doesn't make sense to me since I already know that the vector contains elements of class T. Any alternatives?

Comment: Hello sir. I edited the code just now. Now you only need to type: `ListObjects<Child>(Objects);` instead of `ListObjects<Parent, Child>(Objects);`. This way, it auto figures out (infers) the other type through the vector. All I did was swap the template parameters. I believe that is as good as it gets? Unless you had something else in mind. In that case, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: It might be better to also advise using virtual functions instead of selecting this way.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: that's brilliant, close enough to what I was looking for. Since you clearly know what you're talking about, can you by any means create another response where you'd pass the class as an argument instead of though the diamond inference for the sake of possibilities? THANK YOU!

Comment: @phoad: Virtual functions are for polymorphism. I'm basically depolymorphalyzing my class. How can a virtual funtion help? Please post an example.

Comment: """The result of typeid is a const type_info&. The value is a reference to a type_info object that represents either the type-id or the type of the expression, depending on which form of typeid is used.""" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec.aspx

Comment: So, instead of using templates you might write one function which takes const type_info& as parameter and checks the type_info of the items at the list with this. Otherwise you would have one function definition for each object type, which requires ListObjects to be in a Header file etc.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: I can't thank you enough for your help! Great effort! Now to clarify, let's imagine you have a Book. The Book is an array of Pages*. Each Page can be a WrittenPage or a DrawnPage. If you want to print() all the Pages you use a virtual method. If you just want to print the DrawnPages or WrittenPages you'll have to do some sort of filtering inside the Book. You'll need typeid or some sort of other mean to compare the subtype of each Page. This is how I see it, please correct me if I am wrong. I needed both things but only needed help on the latter.

Comment: @phoad: is that not exactly the code I posted in the first place?

Comment: Seems so. Last update of @CantChooseUsernames is what I wanted to say. And again, there might not be need for another template T to define the vector. Writing "vector<MyObj*>" might be ok.

Comment: @phoad: unless I have a class Map that contains a vector of Places and a vector of Streets. I don't see why anyone would prefer a hard-coded solution in any case, even if they didn't think they'd need it right away.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing this as part of a test just to figure out what is going on somewhere in your code, I agree with commenters that this is a very bad idea.

```
template < typename T >
void listObjects(const std::vector<MyObj*>& vec) {
    for (MyObj* obj: vec) {
        if (typeid(*obj) == typeid(T)) {
            // one of the two below, depending on what your op<< looks like
            std::cout << *obj << std::endl;
            std::cout << dynamic_cast<T&>(*obj) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void calledLikeThis(const std::vector<MyObj*>& vec) {
    listObjects<TheseObj>(vec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are forcing the vector to be of MyObj* which I don't want. The method should received a vector of Template type. I managed to do [ listObjects<subclass_name, superclass_name>(vec); ] But this way I'm forced to type in the superclass_name inside the diammond inference which doesn't make sense to me since I already know that the vector contains elements of class T.

Comment: You may know that, but the compiler doesn't. All the template knows is that you have a type X and you are checking to see if it is also a type Y. It has no reason to suppose that one is a sub-class of the other. After all, the relationship could be reversed, or multiple inheritance could be involved.

Comment: The vector is clearly declared as    vector<MyObj*> vec;    inside my class. Of course there's all sort of cool things going on, but the vector is of that type so the compiler already knows. I created a simple template<T> method that receives a vec and gives me the typeid(vec).name. Works fine when called as method(vec);  without the diamond inference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `typeid` in this manner violates Liskov Substitution principle. LSP, roughly speaking, says that if your function works with objects of class X, it should also work with (some) objects of any subclass of X. Your `listTheseObj` function will only list objects which are *exactly* of type `TheseObj`, but not of any subtype.

That's OK for debugging purposes, or for infrastructure/framework projects, where you implement services like reflection or serialization and index them with `typeid(obj)`. But business logic should not work like that. Users are not interested in whatever technical reason makes you split `TheseObj` into several subtypes; they want *their* notion of type (if at all).

If you want to print only `TheseObj` *and* any subclass-type object, you can replace

```
typeid(*obj) == typeid(TheseObj)
```

with

```
dynamic_cast<TheseObj*>(obj) != 0
```

A templated version would look like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void ListObjects(std::vector<T*> &vec>)
{
    for (T* obj : vec)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<U*>(obj) != 0)
        {
            std::cout<<*obj<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that the body of the `if` doesn't use the condition in any way. This hints on a possibility to separate them.

```
template<typename T>
void ActOnObjects(std::vector<T*> &vec>, std::function<bool(T*)> predicate,
                                         std::function<void(T*)> action)
{
    for (T* obj : vec)
    {
        if (predicate(obj))
        {
            action(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can filter with any predicate, using RTTI or not.

```
ActOnObjects(objects, [](T* obj){return dynamic_cast<ThatObj*>(obj) != 0;},
                      [](T* obj){std::cout << *obj << std::endl;});

ActOnObjects(objects, [](T* obj){return obj->isVeryImportant();},
                      [](T* obj){std::cout << *obj << std::endl;});

ActOnObjects(objects, [](T* obj){return obj->isBlue() && obj->isWobbly();},
                      [](T* obj){std::cout << *obj << std::endl;});
```

Also please use iterator ranges instead of containers, like any good citizen of the C++-land; I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: What's the advantadge of `dynamic_cast<U*>(obj) != 0` over `(typeid(*obj) == typeid(U))`? Without wanting to create many side discussions I just want to say that I read that `typename` could be less effective than `class`, depending on the context, but not the other way around.  About iterators, the only advantage I see in this case is that you can more easlily change your code to suit other containers, correct? Sorry for not addressing the remainder of your answer but to be honest I don't grasp those concepts, I'll need to do some reading before I can get back to you with a better response.

Comment: Dynamic cast will work on a class *and* all of its derived classes, typeid comparison will not. The sentence about typename is false. The statement about iterators is correct (it can be a big advantage).